# How do I read multiple Excel Files into R and then convert them into Fasta files (without concatenating)?

Tags: r, excel, fasta

I have a folder with about 80 Excel files that contain the fastaname in one column and a gene sequence another column. All files have a different number of rows.

I am trying to automate the process of writing an Excel File into a Fasta by reading in all the files I have in one folder and using the command I have for each file.
I do NOT want to have all the data written into a single Fasta file, but want for example the file "gene1.xlsx" as "gene1.fas", "gene2.xlsx" as "gene2.fas" and so on.

The code I am using to convert a single Excel file into a Fasta file is as follows:

```
library(readxl)
library(tibble)
X<-read_excel("*name of the file*.xlsx", col_names=FALSE)
D<-do.call(rbind, lapply (seq(nrow(X)), function(i) t(X[i,])))

write.table(D,file = "*name of the file*.fas", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

I guess that I need a for-loop for that, but I am new to programming and everything I have tried just gave me a single empty Fasta files as the output.

The code I used for that is the following:

```
library(readxl)
library(tibble)

file.list<- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)

library(tibble)
for (i in file.list) {
  B <-do.call(rbind, lapply (seq(nrow(file.list)), function(i) t(file.list[i,])))
  write.table(B,file = "*.fas", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I appreciate any help!
Clara

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data? For example paste `dput(head(X, 15))` from object you create in the third line of your code.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but here is the output if I used your command like this:
dput(head(file.list, 15))
output:
c("./CK_ADNP_marker.xlsx", "./CK_ANKRD50_marker.xlsx", 
"./CK_ARID2_marker.xlsx", "./CKARSI_marker.xlsx", 
"./CK_C-MYC_marker.xlsx", "./CK_CASR_marker.xlsx", 
"./CK_CHST1_marker.xlsx", "./CK_DBC1_marker.xlsx", 
"./CK_DCHS1_marker.xlsx", "./CK_DET1_marker.xlsx", 
"./CK_DMXL1_marker.xlsx", "./CK_DOPEY1_marker.xlsx", 
"./CK_DSEL_marker.xlsx", "./CK_EXOC8_marker.xlsx", 
"./CK_FAT4_marker.xlsx")

Comment: This is helpful, but we need to see if `read_excel()` is reading the file correctly. Try `X <- read_excel(file.list[1], col_names=FALSE)` or `X <- read_excel("./CK_ARID2_marker.xlsx", col_names=FALSE)` to read the first file. Then use `dim(X)` to get the dimensions (rows, columns) and then `str(X)` to see how the data are arranged in the data.frame/tibble.

Comment: Yes! That command seems to work and it looks like it is supposed to look. (column 1 is fastaname and column 2 the sequence and for the ARID marker it is 6 rows which is correct) So the problem seems to be in the for loop.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this for loop that it can work for my purpose (write all Excel files in a folder into Fasta files)?

Comment: Without reproducible data, it is impossible to say. Either provide a sample of the data with `dput(X)` (`dput(head(X, 15))` if it is many rows) or run the code inside your loop for a single file to see if you can get it to work.

Comment: Okay, so pasting everything would be way to many characters with all the sequences; I hope the following helps:
`> dput(head(file.list, 1)) 
list(structure(list(`>Cophyla_berara_FGMV2000-134` = c("fastaname1", "fastaname2" *and many more*), 
"DNA sequence 1", "DNA sequence 2" *and many more*)), row.names = c(NA, -92L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)))`

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this:

[image]

A column of names and a column of sequences.

And the fasta format is:

```
>name1
sequence1
>name2
sequence2
```

And you have a folder containing 80 excel files in the same format.

You can convert one excel to fasta like this

```r
excelfname <- "seqfile1.xlsx"
# I use explicit colun types to make sure that the names are not interpreted as numbers or dates.
seqlist <- read_excel(excelfname,
                      col_names = c("header", "sequence"),
                      col_types = c("text", "text" ))
fastalist <- paste0(">", seqlist$header, "\n", seqlist$sequence)
fastafname <- str_replace(excelfname, "xlsx", "fas")
writeLines(fastalist, con = file(fastafname))
```

Then for many excel files, we can wrap this code in `lapply()`

```r
excelfnames <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
seqlists <- lapply(excelfnames, function(excelfname)
    read_excel(excelfname,
               col_names = c("header", "sequence"),
               col_types = c("text", "text" )))
fastalists <- lapply(seqlists,
                     function(record) paste0(">", record$header, "\n",
                                             record$sequence))
fastafnames <- str_replace(excelfnames, "xlsx", "fas")
names(fastalists) <- fastafnames
lapply(names(fastalists), function(fname) writeLines(fastalists[[fname]],
                                                   con = file(fname)))
```